# how to keep track of newly launched ec2 instance from an ami image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have launched an ec2 instance from an ami using lambda function.
I haven't enabled detailed monitoring. Now I want to keep track of the instances each time lambda set triggered to launch an instance. I want to get an email with instance id  and status of that, when an instance is launched, stops/terminates and instances which running more than 2 hours. I tried cloudwatch, but is instance specific can't get configured for a newly launched instance. I can uses SNS, but how to keep track of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AWS Cloudtrail: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

It gives more info than you are asking for. In cloudtrail, enable SNS Notifications of API activity and set a filter to notify you only when an instance creation/start/stop/terminate etc., For instances that are running for more than 2 hours, you can explore if cloudtrail provides it or it is very easy to write a script using Boto to fetch that information.

There are some AWS partners providing a similar service. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will be better off using an auto scale group and then use the auto scale life cycle hook to get notifications whenever any instance is added or removed. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-lifecycle-hooks.html
When you use the life cycle hooks, you can have an SNS notification to not only get intimidated about the new instance but also take custom actions.
You can still use the aws lambda function to continue adding and removing new instances, only that you will increase and decrease the size of the auto scaling group.

Comment: Thanks @rohit, But i don't require autoscaling. I work on a single instance at a item. Once the task is completed I will terminate that instance.

Comment: Autoscaling was not specified